# Execute Code only when lockbutton was pressed (iphone objective-c)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, home-button

I made an app that should execute code when the phone is locked with the app active. This action calls the following methods:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Here comes the issue: I don not want to execute the same code when the user presses the homebutton!!! but pressing the homebutton calls exactly the same methods!

Is there a way to do something like this

```
if(homebuttonPressed) do this; else do something else;
```

Thank you for reading this and helping me

Greets